# Why is $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \, \|B\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

Both $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional matrices. Why is $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \, \|B\|$?

Comment: Where $\|A\|$ means what?

Comment: There is no "why". If your matrix norm satisfies the inequality, it is called *submultiplicative*, otherwise it is not submultiplicative. Some matrix norms are submultiplicative and some are not. If you have a specific matrix norm in mind, please state it.

Comment: @user1551 what norm is it in the existing answer then?

Comment: I don't know. You should look up the relevant definition from your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A(x)\|$. This implies that for $x\neq 0$, $\|A({x\over{\|x\|}})\leq \|A\|$. We deduce that $\|A(x)\|\leq\|A\|\|x\|$.

This implies that $\|AB\|=Sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A(B(x))\|\leq sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A\|\|B(x)\|\leq sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A\|\|B\|\|x\|=\|A\|\|B\|$.